# Pythonic way of creating simple and complex version of two function calls (ie overloading a function)

Tags: python

I have two functions I would like to make use of: a complex version and a simple version.

complex: `u.upload("name2", "cat2", "mod2")`

simple `u.upload("name2")`

I would like to keep the default parameters as globals inside the .py file.

uploader.py

```
category_s = ""
model_s = ""

def upload(name, category = category_s, model = model_s):
    print(name, category, model)
    upload(name, category, model, author, asRoot = True)
```

script.py

```
import uploader as u

u.category_s = "cat1"
u.model_s = "mod1"
u.upload("name1")
u.upload("name2", "cat2", "mod2")
```

Output

```
name1 
name2, cat2, mod2
```

Desired Output

```
name1, cat1, mod1
name2, cat2, mod2
```

It's as if def upload(category = **category_s**) doesn't see category_s. I have tried calling category_s as a global, and it still doesn't work.

Is there a pythonic way of achieving this? In another language, I would overload the upload function and make a class to hold the category and model variables. I thought I would be able to use the parameter assignment and a global variable at the top the achieve the same thing.

**Edit:** Figured out what the problem is. `category = category_s` inside the function definition is evaluated when upload.py is imported. So whatever value it is set to, it cannot be changed upon future `category_s = ...` modifications. Is there any way to get around this behavior? Or would I want to? Is there a better way to achieve what I am going for? I want a simple function that I am going to use 99% of the time, with the option to call the complex parameters. The catch is I also want to periodically change the default parameters in the simple function.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, default function parameters are evaluated ONCE, at the time the function is defined - further changes to `category_s` and `model_s` do not affect the default values.  Yes, this leads to all sorts of surprises...

To achieve a changeable default, do something like this:

```
def upload(name, category = None, model = None):
    if category is None:
        category = category_s
    if model is None:
        model = model_s
    print(name, category, model)
```

You may need to choose a different default value if `None` is a potential actual value for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could move it into an object and use parameters first and then fallback to attributes.

```
class Uploader:

def __init__(self, category="", model=""):
    self.category_s = category
    self.model_s = model

def setCategory(self, category):
    self.category_s = category

def setModel(self, model):
    self.model_s = model

def upload(self, name, category=None, model=None):
    print(name, category or self.category_s, model or self.model_s)
```

And other code

```
from uploader import Uploader

u = Uploader()
u.category_s = "cat1"
u.model_s = "mod1"
u.upload("name1")
u.upload("name2", "cat2", "mod2")
```

Output

```
('name1', 'cat1', 'mod1')
('name2', 'cat2', 'mod2')
```